# how to split 0000000+00:00 from time in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove 0000000+00:00 from the pandas column but I am unable to do that I have a data frame column in which i have the time in this format HH:MM but there is an extra part coming along with the time
**0000000+00:00**.

I have the dataframe column values in this format

```
0       19:57:00.0000000+00:00
1       19:57:00.0000000+00:00
2       19:59:00.0000000+00:00
3       21:57:00.0000000+00:00
```

I need to remove 0000000+00:00 from the data frame column I have also tried this

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'], format='%H:%M')
```

it gives **unconverted data remains: :00.0000000+00:00**

I have also tried splitting it

```
df['Duration'].str.split('.')
```

this gives the list

```
0       [19:57:00, 0000000+00:00]
1       [19:57:00, 0000000+00:00]
2       [19:59:00, 0000000+00:00]
3       [21:57:00, 0000000+00:00]
```

still i need to convert into hours and mins but failed to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `str.replace` here:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].str.replace('\.\d+\+\d{2}:\d{2}$', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If duration of datetime type, so, in order to keep it as a date type, I suggest use the following:

```
df['duration']=df['duration'].apply(lambda x:x.date())
```

```
df['duration']=df['duration'].apply(lambda x:x.time())
```